# How to access dataset of cartodbs local instance using SQL API

Tags: sql, cartodb

I am new to cartodb. And `https://{account}.cartodb.com/api/v2/sql?q=SELECT * FROM {table_name} LIMIT 1` this will retrieve all records for a particular table. I would like to know how to retrieve dataset for my local cartodb account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell exactly what you're asking, but you're probably looking to get into CartoDB's createLayer method (assuming you're making a map)... it's going to look something like this:

```
    var layerSource = {
           user_name: '[YOUR USERNAME]',
           type: 'cartodb',
           cartodb_logo: true,
           sublayers: [{
                sql: "SELECT * FROM **your table** WHERE xxx LIKE 'sample'" 
                },
                {
                sql: "SELECT * FROM winston_survey_tool WHERE point_class LIKE 'Survey point'"
                }]
               };
```

But you should really just check out CartoDB's documentation on all of this: http://academy.cartodb.com/courses/03-cartodbjs-ground-up/lesson-1.html or perhaps http://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-platform/cartodb-js/sql/